# Get recursive material costs (Bill of Materials)

Tags: recursion

I am trying to write a program to compute the total material costs of an item in production.
So far, I figured out a recursive algorithm might be the best way to do this. While I learned about them in school, we have always avoided them in any practical tasks.

As an example, this will have to do:

```
1 Kitchen requires 1 Table and 2 Chairs
1 Chair requires 4 Legs
1 Table requires 4 Legs and 1 Plate
```

Thus, 1 Kitchen requires 12 Legs and 1 Plate (the Table and Chairs should be omitted, as they are intermediate products)

However, I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to actually write the recursive function.

*NOTE:* If you believe this question is not useful to the community or otherwise of bad quality, please leave a comment on what could improve this question.

Comment: The input is a string? The first step would be to parse that into something useful.

Comment: No, the input is an item. A, B, C and D should only represent different kinds of items

Comment: How do you input the relationships?

Comment: An item knows what other items it required. E.g. a kitchen knows it requires 1 table and 2 chairs. A table knows it needs 4 legs and 1 plate. As pseudocode `item.requirements` is a list of item-quantity structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar in pseudo-code and I am not sure what programming language you are familiar with. Hence I try to answer it in code form.

Recursive method : CollectRawProduct(Product)

```
CollectRawProduct(Product product) {
    if (product has subProducts) {
        for ( subProduct : subProducts ) { // iterates the sub products
            CollectRawProduct( subProduct ); // visit subproduct
        }
    } else {
        rawProductList.add(product) // add to a raw product list
    }
}
```

The raw product list will contain the raw product like e.g for your case 4 legs one plate.